# Which electronic switch to use with 5V as triggering signal and 12 V as actual signal?

Tags: arduino, switches, power-electronics, 12v, triac

Which electronic switch should I use if I want to control 12 V,1A signal with a 5V Arduino output signal? (12 V is high powered signal so I can't use s boosted 12 V output from a 5 V Arduino signal - Image is below]l.)

Some specs:

- The switch should work instantaneously (Edit: 10-20 milliseconds maximum.)
- Only triggering ON is needed. If an option is available through which we can only trigger on and later turn it off in any other way, that option is welcome too

I have tried:

- MOSFET but I guess it doesn't work for gate voltage 5V if 12 V signal needs to be passed through.
- Triac & optocoupler - it turns on alright but it's not turning off in any way I know

[image]

Comment: "MOSFET but I heard it doesn't work work for gate voltage 5V." You've heard wrong. Google logic level MOSFET.

Comment: Quantify "instantaneously". It seems to me that a relay (maybe with a hold circuit) will do what you describe, but it has some switching delay.

Comment: If it will not ruin some other plan use an N Channel mosfet as your electronic switch and put it on the ground side of the actuator. That way you do not need to level shift the gate voltage.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen in 10 -20 ms max

Comment: That sounds like a relay would be OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a tip122 transistor. Which is one of the standard driver transistors for coils and such.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a CMOS transistor to allow for rapid switching from low-power to high-power. The propagation delays are usually around 25 nS to 50 nS.

SCR is another thought...

And if you are looking for further control of your actuator check this link out.

[Interfacing TTL and CMOS Circuits](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019MNOSA2)

Answer (score 0):

You’re looking for an NPN transistor.

The circuit below is almost correct.

> [image]
>
> https://teachmetomake.wordpress.com/how-to-use-a-transistor-as-a-switch/

Instead of connecting the input voltage to the board, use a separate 12V source. 
Just be sure to use a common ground.

Bringing the pwm signal up above the transistor’s “on” voltage closes the switch and allows the 12Vs to flow.

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of current you probably want a relay with a 5V coil. You could use something like a [TE HF353](https://datasheet.octopart.com/HF353-Axicom-datasheet-49264298.pdf) if you want to solder it into a PCB or there are a ton of larger relays with screw terminals out there.